# What's the minSdkVersion version for twilio chat on android?

Tags: twilio

Have an app that is implementing twilio-chat. Everything is working only that I can't have run it on devices with version below 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

By default the minSdkVersion is 21. You can override it down to 14 though.

Comment: If I override to 14, will everything work as it should?